# Как отследить, что вставка не удалась при batchInsert?

Tags: php, yii2

При использовании `ActiveRecord`, метод `save` возвращает результат успешности произведённой операции. Если я хочу вставить много записей, я хочу использовать `batchInsert`.

Но как отследить, вставились ли именно **все** записи? И что, если хоть одна не вставилась - то откатить транзацкцию? Потому что всё, что возвращает метод - количество затронутых строк. Использовать его и сопоставлять с количеством записей, которые я хочу внести? Как корректно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$items = [[1, 'name'], [2, 'name2']];

$query = (new Query())->createCommand()->batchInsert(
    'tableName',
    ['id', 'name'],
    $items
);

if ($query->execute() != count($items)) {// rollback}
```

Comment: Т.е. это единственный хороший способ? Почему AR возвращает успешность операции а тут..

Comment: Потому что в данном случае нет смысла выявлять успешность/неуспешность операции. Методу дали массив данных, он сказал, сколько получилось добавить. Остальная логика отдана на откуп клиенту. Методу не надо знать насколько доволен результатом будет клиент. Может кого-то устроит, если хотя бы 90% данных будет добавлено. Наверно так.